# Reading a specific number of bytes from a socket in perl

Tags: perl, sockets

I'm trying to emulate some small parts of a HTTP api (to test some scripts against - the scripts are meant to run against some software implementing the complete API, but making that run and feeding it initial data for testing is hard).

So far I have a small perl script using IO::Socket::INET to listen to TCP connections, that works fine for emulating GET requests, but I also have to handle some POST requests, and for that I'm a little stuck. I read the headers just fine, and find e.g. 'Content-Length: 20', but then I have to read those 20 bytes which often does not end with a newline.

I've tried

```
$client_socket->recv($data, $content_length);
```

and

```
sysread $client_socket, $data, $content_length;
```

but both only return when they recieve an EOL (I haven't checked whether they need `\n`, `\r` or both as it doesn't really matter), but then only return the number of bytes I asked for.

I probably haven't searched for the right words, all I've found is that the timeout you can set on a IO::Socket::INET is only used for the connection, and if I use IO::Socket::Timeout or wrap the read in an eval-block with an alarm, nothing is read.

---

As the comments revealed that something else was going on, I dug on. It seems `$socket->recv` changes behaviour if I have previously read from the socket with `$data = <$socket>`, am example (not a complete script - I don't think it's interesting, but if someone wants one I can supply one):

```
$client_socket->recv($data, 4);
print "1: $data\n";
$data = <$client_socket>;
print "2: $data\n";
$client_socket->recv($data, 4); 
print "3: $data\n";
```

This only outputs lines with `1:` and `2:` when several lines are sent on the socket (I just used `curl` to generate several (7 I think) lines of data).

Comment: If you can install extra stuff, think about using Mojolicious::Lite or Dancer2 instead. Will save you a lot of typing and pain. Something like `perl -MDancer2 -e ' get "/" => sub { return to_json {foo => "bar"} }; dance'` as a start is great, then make it into a script. Run either with the built-in server, or use `plackup`.

Comment: *but both only return when they recieve an EOL* - this indicates that the sender is not flushing its output. You are not clear about the process that produces data for your socket to consume.

Comment: Re "*but both only return when they recieve an EOL*", No, they don't. both `sysread` and `recv` returns as soon as there is data. Perhaps the sender is buffering its output.

Comment: Or maybe you only think you haven't received anything because your program's output is buffered.

Comment: I've tested using both `telnet` and `curl` to send requests. I have no problem believing that telnet might not send data until I press enter, but I think `curl` should do it properly, and with tcpdump I could see that data was actually sent.

Comment: And I've been cheated by buffered output from that script before, so I have made sure that's not the problem in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `read $client_socket, $data, 4`, I got some code that did what I wanted.